# Why outer measure by Jordan of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ and $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ is 1?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can you expain in details why outer measure by Jordan of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ and $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ is 1?

Comment: Do you have any difficulties in following the definition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The result is a consequence of:

1. If $\mathcal C = \{[a_1, b_1], \dots , [a_n,b_n]\}$ is a finite cover of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$, then $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal C$. The proof is based on the fact that $[0,1] \setminus \bigcup \mathcal C$ is open in $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$.
2. If $[0,1]$ is included in a finite cover of closed intervals $[a_i,b_i]$ then $\sum\limits_i (b_i-a_i) \ge 1$. The proof can be done by induction.